# Making the nao robot say something that is stored in a variable using python

Tags: python, nao-robot

I am making a Luis (Microsoft AI) and Nao linkage so when I ask my Nao robot something he can send the request to Luis and tell me an answer. But for that I have an answer that I store in a variable (lets call it answerL) and I want Nao to say what is in this answer with a python script since all the program is in Python. I didn't found anything in the Aldebaran documentation to do that with the "say" command from the ALTextToSpeechProxy. Is there another way or did I miss something ?

Thanks

L

Answer (score 2):

From documentation [Making NAO Speak](http://doc.aldebaran.com/1-14/dev/python/making_nao_speak.html)

```
from naoqi import ALProxy
tts = ALProxy("ALTextToSpeech", "<IP of your robot>", 9559)
tts.say("Hello, world!")
```

You simply pass the words you want spoken as a string to `tts.say`
So assuming that Microsoft Luis bot gives you some result/answer as a string, just call the `say` method with that string as an argument.

```
answer = MadeUpLiusAPI.get_answer("some question")
tts.say(answer)
```